# change user within bash script

Tags: bash, scripting, permissions

I have a simple bash script which runs great as a regular user.  When launched from postfix, it runs as nobody:nobody which prevents many commands from working.

Is it possible for the script to change to another user account while running, to allow these other programs to run?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905697/how-to-run-script-as-another-user-without-password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to configure `sudo` so that you can run a specific command as `nobody` which will run as another user.

Typically, something like (in your `sudoers` file):

```
nobody ALL=(userTheScriptShouldRunAs) NOPASSWD: /home/userTheScriptShouldRunAs/test.sh
```

Then, get your script to execute:

```
sudo -u userTheScriptShouldRunAs /home/userTheScriptShouldRunAs/test.sh
```

Comment: I think this is the only way...I don't like to sudo a script callable from a mail message but no option.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set a program's permissions with the [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) bit:

> chown usertorunas filename
>
> chmod ug+s filename

That will make it run as the user who owns the file.

However, as @Jay reminded me, it doesn't work for scripts.  To run a script as a different user you need to make a small program [as explained here](http://www.tuxation.com/setuid-on-shell-scripts.html) which CAN be setuid, and calls your script.

Comment: You can't set setuid bits on scripts, too much of a security risk.